# Wrong first argument in system

Tags: ruby, system

In a git repository. I want to get the number of commits against remote `origin`'s master branch:

```
remote = 'origin'
system %W[git rev-list HEAD...#{remote}/master --count]
```

This will result in `ArgumentError: wrong first argument`.

But `git rev-list HEAD...#{remote}/master --count` works.

what's wrong with my first argument?

Answer (score 9):

Need to use splat operator to convert the array to method parameters:

```
system *%W[git rev-list HEAD...#{remote}/master --count]
```